# Is there anything that a Bash script can accomplish that other scripting languages cannot?

Tags: bash, scripting

I've written a few dozen Bash scripts for my Mac over the years, although probably 80% of Bash code I have is in `.bash_profile`. Lately I've been doing things I used to do with Bash by using Python instead.

So, given languages like Python or Ruby (or even PHP), with the exception of login scripts such as `.bash_profile` (which may not be an exception), are there any tasks that Bash can do that generic scripting languages cannot?

Comment: "Is there anything that an X script can accomplish that other scripting languages cannot?", for **any** value of X, is opinion-based flamebait. There are definitely things that are much easier to do *tersely* in bash, but once you get into discussion of which things it is and isn't valuable to have special syntax for your question is off in the land of dueling opinions.

Comment: Regarding the hold, I disagree that this is primarily opinion-based. I'm asking for a factual answer, not whether Bash is better or worse than a generic scripting language, but whether things are possible in Bash that aren't elsewhere.

Comment: "Can something be done in language-X that can't be done in language-Y?" is categorically false for **every Turing-equivalent language**, unless you're asking if a language has hooks or facilities that go beyond computation and into side-effecting operations with the rest of the world or OS.

Comment: And the thing about side-effecting hooks and facilities is that (once again, categorically) any hook you can add for one language you can add for another, and/or add a translation layer for. If you have, say, a GUI library in Python/C/C++/TCL/whatever it's going to be possible -- even if impractical -- to implement the same library for any other language, even if it's doing something crazy inefficient like converting that  higher-level API to a socket-based shim.

Comment: So if the question is read in a strict and limited enough matter to make it *not* flamebait, then it's meaningless in that its answer is guaranteed by principals introduced in any good CS101 course, and not specific to the individual language being asked about at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash is oldschool UNIX - pulling little utilities together to achieve a greater goal mostly by using pipes and plumbing output from one command to the next.

There is definitely a lot to be said for having the skills involved in this style of seat of the pants programming. Too many people head off and write a self contained program to achieve something that can be done using a few command line inputs.

So in answer to your question , yes. A bash script can teach you to understand the multitude of bash scripts out there and it can do most things on a UNIX box in close to the most efficient way. Bash is here to stay.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off, bash is itself a shell, so it comes with builtin features like job control (suspend, etc.), file handle/terminal redirection (`2 &> 1` and friends) and terminal control (like being able to display the current path in the titlebar, etc.). Other languages that don't have a built-in shell with access to termcap don't have those abilities. Pipe redirection is hard to get right (python's `subprocess.popen` has a bunch of limitations due to threads and potential deadlocks for example, while bash has access to `tee` etc.)

Comment: Absolutely everything bash can do (re: process substitution, command substitution, pipeline setup, &c) can be done with `subprocess.Popen`. Not necessarily *easily*, absolutely not tersely, but *can be done*. That includes use of `tee` (which is, after all, an external command and can be `exec`'d by a Python interpreter just as easily as it can be `exec`'d by bash).

Comment: sure, but any semi-robust solution requires wrangling threads, which is not trivial vs. a bash 1/2 liner. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python

Comment: Eh? The "non-blocking" requirement making that ticket complicated (and necessitating use of threads) isn't something bash supports or has any need of -- the bash-native way to do things is to fork off a subprocess (which does individually blocking operations), which Python is equally capable of doing.

Comment: That said, I fully and wholeheartedly agree (as someone who uses both tools extensively and regularly) that there are jobs where bash is a more appropriate tool than Python. However, that's (1) a very opinion-centric case-by-case determination, and (2) not, strictly, what the OP asked.

Comment: I posted the wrong one. Here's a couple of questions on how to implement `tee`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833897/python-read-from-subprocess-stdout-and-stderr-separately-while-preserving-order https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926470/run-command-and-get-its-stdout-stderr-separately-in-near-real-time-like-in-a-te

Comment: "Implement" `tee`? If we were behaving as an analog of the equivalent bash, we'd just be using an OS-provided `/usr/bin/tee`, exactly as bash does. Which is to say, once again you're setting a higher bar for the Python than you do for the bash we're talking about replacing.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Bash is written in C, and the programs it runs are written in other languages (which are usually either C or implemented in C).  Thus, everything that Bash does can be — and already is — done by other programming languages.