# Live-output / stream from Python subprocess

Tags: python, stream, console, subprocess

I am using Python and it's subprocess library to check output from calls using strace, something in the matter of:

```
subprocess.check_output(["strace", str(processname)])
```

However, this only gives me the output **after** the called subprocess already finished, which is very limiting for my use-case.

I need a kind of "stream" or live-output from the process, so I need to read the output **while** the process is still running instead of only after it finished.

Is there a convenient way to achieve this using the subprocess library?
I'm thinking of a kind of poll every x seconds, but did not find any hints regarding on how to implement this in the documentation.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had some problems referencing the [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54091788/319862) for streaming output from a test runner.  The following worked better for me:

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep

def stream_process(process):
    go = process.poll() is None
    for line in process.stdout:
        print(line)
    return go

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while stream_process(process):
    sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Just to say this worked perfectly for our use case, thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 18):

As of Python 3.2 (when context manager support was added to `Popen`), I have found this to be the most straightforward way to continuously stream output from a subprocess:

```
import subprocess


def run(args):
  with subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as process:
    for line in process.stdout:
      print(line.decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: works under py3.8.5.  Much more elegant than previous solutions - i wonder if there are any nuances here?  One disadvantage relative to a previous `.poll()` based I was using is one can't timeout in all cases (this method _must_ block indefinitely for a line or `EOF`) ... but still quite elegant

Comment: I would also `rstrip` like so: `line.decode("utf8").rstrip("\n")` to not add extra newlines to output. Otherwise this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#popen-):

`Popen.poll()`

> Check if child process has terminated. Set and return returncode attribute.

So based on this you can:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('your_command_here',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if process.poll() is not None and output == '':
        break
    if output:
        print (output.strip())
retval = process.poll()
```

This will loop, reading the stdout, and display the output in real time.

---

This does not work in current versions of python. (At least) for Python 3.8.5 and newer you should replace `output == ''` with `output == b''`

Comment: Suppose I don't want to simply print:
I have a separate thread relying on the data that gets put out in real time. How would I go about accessing this data as elegantly as possible?

Besides that, thank you for your answer :-)

Comment: The data which is extracted from the process using the procedure above is meant to be processed in a function running in a parallel thread.

Comment: So, instead of printing the `output` variable you will be feeding it into your function. I'd suggest using a `Queue` - which will contain the `output` produced by `strace` - and have your parallel thread consume data from this queue as soon as they're available. Check [this](https://www.troyfawkes.com/learn-python-multithreading-queues-basics/) out.

Comment: One more question: What is the retval = process.poll() for?

Comment: I'm guessing subprocess changed since you answered b/c I had to change `... and output == ''` to `... and output == b''` because `process.stdout.readline()` is returning byte string. Otherwise the loop never terminates.

Comment: @even with the change suggested by Nathan this does not seem to work well. It works for command='pwd' but it already fails for 'pwd; sleep 5 ; pwd' with the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pwd ; sleep 4 ; pwd'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat stdout and stderr separately, you can spawn two threads that handle them concurrently (live as the output is produced).

Adapted from my more detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76634163/5511061):

```py
import logging
from collections import deque
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial
from subprocess import PIPE, CalledProcessError, CompletedProcess, Popen


def stream_command(
    args,
    *,
    stdout_handler=logging.info,
    stderr_handler=logging.error,
    check=True,
    text=True,
    stdout=PIPE,
    stderr=PIPE,
    **kwargs,
):
    """Mimic subprocess.run, while processing the command output in real time."""
    with Popen(args, text=text, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, **kwargs) as process:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:  # two threads to handle the streams
            exhaust = partial(pool.submit, partial(deque, maxlen=0))
            exhaust(stdout_handler(line[:-1]) for line in process.stdout)
            exhaust(stderr_handler(line[:-1]) for line in process.stderr)
    retcode = process.poll()
    if check and retcode:
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args)
    return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode)
```

Call with simple `print` handlers:

```py
stream_command(["echo", "test"], stdout_handler=print, stderr_handler=print)
# test
```

Or with custom handlers:

```py
outs, errs = [], []
def stdout_handler(line):
    outs.append(line)
    print(line)
def stderr_handler(line):
    errs.append(line)
    print(line)

stream_command(
    ["echo", "test"],
    stdout_handler=stdout_handler,
    stderr_handler=stderr_handler,
)
# test
print(outs)
# ['test']
```

Comment: I am curious. Why do you suggest starting a pool of thread workers to push results of the stream handlers into a zero-sized container? Is it only to avoid using for loops, or what am I missing?

Comment: @Smartskaft2 the deque with maxlen=0 is a shortcut to exhaust an iterable (see [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)). My answer basically does `for _ in iterable: pass` inside a thread. This way, `stdout_handler` and `stderr_handler` handler get called asynchronously, live as the lines come into the `stdout` and `stderr` buffers.

Comment: if you're OK with redirecting stderr buffer to `stdout_handler`, you can avoid the ThreadPoolExecutor and use a single for-loop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76626021/5511061

Comment: if you replace the threadpool with two for loops, only the first for loop will be processing its buffer 'live': only when that first buffer is exhausted (subprocess has finished), the second for loop starts reading from its buffer (not 'live').