# Python listen to iftop

Tags: python, linux, networking

I'm trying to build some kind of parser of iftop data on Linux server.
I'm trying to build it with python but doesn't seem that I can get live console output.

Anyone has any ideas how can I show iftop in my python file?

This is what I'm trying to run:

```
 subprocess.Popen(["iftop -t"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, text=True)
```

Comment: perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091396/live-output-stream-from-python-subprocess) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command)

Comment: @Yarin_007 it's always returning just https://prnt.sc/iwz81uL7MzrW